# How to deploy Symfony application? Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Experts:

Im having the error message when trying to run an application of Symfony in my VPS:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/vendor/zendframework/zend-cache/src/Storage/AdapterPluginManager.php on line 27

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)' in /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/vendor/zendframework/zend-cache/src/Storage/AdapterPluginManager.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} Next exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException' with message 'Circular reference detected for service "ps_pdf.listener", path: "ps_pdf.listener -> ps_pdf.cache".' in /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2114 Stack trace: #0 /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/app/cache/prod/classes.php(2350): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('ps_pdf.listener') #1 /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/app/cache/prod/classes.php(2338): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.controll...') #2 /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/app/bootstrap.php.cache(3091): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwa in /home/mgdatos/public_html/nival7/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2114
```

Could you please give me a clue?

Comment: The second message indicates a container configuration issue.  Setup a development machine and get your app running before trying to deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I had to upgrade to 5.6 php version.